# How to create search filter for searching in table in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create search for the table, but couldn't get any ideas for how to create search filter. I am trying   it from firebase database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. If you have any code you've tried, look into providing a [mre]. Please note: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Once you have more information, please [edit] your question.